# Как изменять значения свойства объекта по ссылке?

Tags: java

В Java можно как-то изменять свойства по ссылке подобным образом?

```
createBoard(this.boardLeft);
createBoard(this.boardRight);

private void createBoard(Models.Board board)
{
    board = new Models.Board();
}
```

Соответственно, в контексте будут изменены свойства, которые были переданы в качестве аргумента.

К примеру, простейшая реализация в PHP:

```
private $field1;
private $field2;

$this->createField($this->field);
$this->createField($this->field);

private function ($fieldName) {
    $this->$fieldName = new Field();
}
```

Comment: Вы можете вызывать методы и изменять поля в `board`, но `board = new Models.Board();` создаёт новый объект класса, старый при этом никуда не девается и никак не изменяется. По сути, вы просто ссылку на старый объект заменяете на ссылку на новый объект.

Comment: Приведите полностью кейс, который нужно решить. Я не могу представить, в какой ситуации такое могло бы потребоваться - скорее всего, вам просто нужен другой подход. Отдельно замечу, что в PHP-примере модифицируется поле объекта.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться поручать постороннему коду устанавливать поля класса так же, как вам не хочется поручать другим жевать за вас еду. Поля класса и само их наличие — внутреннее частное дело класса.

Comment: Код вызван в контексте объекта, свойство которого нужно изменить. Просто интересны возможности языка, и не более.

Comment: Если делать правильно, всё работает. Правильно так: `private Models.Board createBoard() { return new Models.Board(); } this.boardLeft = createBoard(); this.boardRight = createBoard();`. Создатели Java не заморачивались с поддержкой неправильных конструкций.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так и делал изначально, но, потом захотелось как-то "извратиться" ))

Comment: @JILeXanDR: Подумайте, какого типа должно быть `$fieldName` в вашем случае на Java.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в Джаве нельзя. В C# можно.

Твой метод должен вернуть нечто, а вызывающая стороная должна сама выполнить присваивание.

Comment: Так и пришлось сделать...)

Answer (score 2):

Это "жжж" неспроста.

Наличие такой возможности нарушило бы инкапсуляцию класса. Представьте, что класс `Пчёлы` передает значение своего поля `Тучка` в метод другого класса `Медведь`. Тот класс написан хакером Винни-Пухом. Он заменяет полученный объект собственным и записывает в поле `Тучка` ссылку на новый объект класса `МедвеТучка`. Теперь внутренняя целостность `Пчёлы` нарушена. База данных `Мёд` в опасности.

Кстати, ещё в вашем примере неверное наименование метода получается. `createBoard` должен возвращать новый экземпляр класса Board. Аналогично `newBoard`. Метод, который меняет полученный объект мог бы называться `setupBoard` или `initBoard`.

Comment: Может, это был неправильный мёд?

Comment: Конечно! Классика же!

Comment: Нет там никакого нарушения внутреннего состояния. Если класс сам передал нечто по ссылке, то это то же самое, как если бы он получил возвращаемое значение и сам присвоил. Большинство языков это позволяют. А в джаве просто решили, что это лишняя фича. Вот и всё. PS: Минус не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy я имею в виду более общую ситуацию, когда класс просто отдает свое поле куда-то параметром. Например C# это позволяет, но с использованием ключевых слов, которые отражаются в сигнатуре метода. Таким образом класс-клиент знает, "на что подписывается" .

Comment: Нет, ну понятно, что byref as default - это не круто. От такого подхода отказались уже. Но полная невозможность передачи - это тоже плохо, на мой взгляд. А шарповское ключевое слово при вызове - оно только на уровне языка. На самом деле, способ передачи задаётся сигнатурой вызываемого метода, а не вызывающим кодом.

Comment: @Qwertiy я вроде бы это же самое и имел в виду. :)